# How to compute the result after two perspective transformations?

Tags: opencv, graphics, perspective, homography

I am doing an image stitching project using OpenCV. Now I have the homography **H1** between img1 and img2, and the homography **H2** between img2 and img3. Now I need to compute the homography between img1 and img3, simply multiply **H1*H2** is not working.

Are any ideas to calculate the new homography between img1 and img3?

Comment: homographies are directional. Let's say pX is a pixel in image X and HX is the homography from imageX to imageX-1, then for example p1=H1*p2 and p2=H2*p3; then p1 = H1*H2*p3; You can revert the direction by inverting the homography matrix. Can you show by example how he images and homographies look like in your case?

Comment: I have two homographies: the first one is
`   ([[1.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 1.8e+03],
       [0.0e+00, 1.0e+00, 5.0e+01],
       [0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 1.0e+00]])`
and another is
`([[ 9.49534471e-01, -5.81765975e-03,  6.67917766e+01],
       [-1.13810490e-02,  9.81450515e-01, -6.72362563e-01],
       [-1.47974585e-04,  9.92770511e-06,  1.00000000e+00]])`

Comment: if I simply multiply them, it is not the result I need. I‘m not sure what do you mean about the " revert the direction by inverting the homography matrix"?

Comment: which directions are your H1 and H2 do you feed points from image1 to H1 or do you feed images from image2 to H1?

Comment: ok, got it. The H1 is from img2 to img1, H2 is from img3 to img2. Now I need new homography from img3 to img1.

Comment: see my answer. How do you apply the homographies to the points? Do you use cv2.perspectiveTransform or do you manually multiply points by matrices? Do you handle the homogeneous coordinates right (divide by z coordinate)? Maybe you will have to divide the whole matrix by the last element (if it differs from 1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me computing `H1 * H2` works well and gives the right results.
Here, `H1 = H2_1` since it warps from image2 to image1.
`H2 = H3_2` since it warps from image3 to image2.
`H1 * H2 = H3_1` since it warps from image3 to image 1.

```
int main()
{
    try {
        cv::Mat H2_1 = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 1.8e+03, 0.0e+00, 1.0e+00, 5.0e+01, 0.0e+00, 0.0e+00, 1.0e+00);
        cv::Mat H3_2 = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 0.949534471, -0.00581765975, 66.7917766, -0.0113810490, 0.981450515, -0.672362563, -0.000147974585, 0.00000992770511, 1.0);


        cv::Mat H3_1 = H2_1 * H3_2;

        cv::Point2f p3(500, 500);

        std::vector<cv::Point2f> src3;
        src3.push_back( p3 );
        src3.push_back(p3);
        std::vector<cv::Point2f> dst2;

        cv::perspectiveTransform(src3, dst2, H3_2);
        std::cout << "p1: " << p3 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "p2: " << dst2[0] << std::endl;

        std::vector<cv::Point2f> dst1;
        cv::perspectiveTransform(dst2, dst1, H2_1);
        std::cout << "p1 from p2: " << dst1[0] << std::endl;

        dst1.clear();
        cv::perspectiveTransform(src3, dst1, H3_1);
        std::cout << "p1 from p3: " << dst1[0] << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is the 'perspectiveTransform()' same as 'warpPerspective()', cuz in this case I need stitch images using their matching points using python.

Comment: warpPerspective is using the same kind of transformation to transform pixel values according to pixel positions. perspectiveTransform only transforms list of pixel positions. So if you use warpPerspective with H3_1 you could warp image3 to image1. If you use perspectiveTransform with H3_1 you could a list of coordinates from image3 to image1.

Comment: thanks. In my task. I used warpimg1 = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, H2_1,(600, 240)) to align the image2 to image1 and it works. But for 
warpimg2 = cv2.warpPerspective(img3, H2_1*H3_2,(600, 240)), when I align the 3rd image to 1 image, it not working. I tried your code and it goodm however why in this case it's wrong. Am I missed something?

Comment: this only makes sense if H2_1 is warping from image1 to image2 (not from image2 to image1), so probably your direction is the other way around, which means that you probably have to perform H2*H1 instead of H1*H2 to combine both transformations.

Comment: Thank you I suddenly realized that I should use np.matmul () instead of np.multiply(). LOL